# (Postgres) Index that Answers the question "is null" or "is not null"

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a table with a column that is a nullable `timestamp`, for historical reasons. However, as the code has progressed over the years, we basically ended up treating it as a boolean: basically, `is null` or `is not null`.

Is there a way I can index this column to speed-up `is null` and `is not null` queries on this column?

One thing I tried is something like:

```sql
create index <name> on <table> ((<column> is null))
```

And this seems to work for `is null` queries. But, postgres doesn't seem to use this index for `is not null` queries, even if I try to coerce it with some clumsy syntax like `where (<column> is null) = false`.

And before anyone suggests it: yes, I'm aware that we should just change the column to a boolean, but there's a *ton* of code that uses it, including legacy clients that can't be changed because customers can't or won't upgrade

**EDIT:**

Here's an example query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM table1
  WHERE obj_id = ?
    AND deleted_at IS NULL
    AND mute_until IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY updated_at DESC
  LIMIT ?
) a
  LEFT JOIN table2 b
    ON a.last_id = b.id
ORDER BY a.updated_at
```

`mute_until` is the field that we're treating as a boolean. Though, in this query, `deleted_at` is also, essentially, treated as a boolean, too. In our use-cases, it makes sense to mark *when* it was deleted, but when we query, we either need to query all undeleted rows (ie, `deleted_at is null`), or *all* rows (ie, no where condition on `deleted_at`).

The index I've created is:

```sql
create index table1_obj_id_deleted_at_mute_until_index
on table1 (obj_id,(deleted_at is null),(mute_until is null))
```

The example query plan:

```sql
 Sort  (cost=24.37..24.38 rows=1 width=2524) (actual time=0.764..0.788 rows=0 loops=1)
   Output: --65 columns--
   Sort Key: table1.updated_at
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   Buffers: shared hit=9
   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=16.33..24.36 rows=1 width=2524) (actual time=0.626..0.628 rows=0 loops=1)
         Output: --65 columns--
         Inner Unique: true
         Buffers: shared hit=9
         ->  Limit  (cost=15.91..15.91 rows=1 width=1448) (actual time=0.614..0.615 rows=0 loops=1)
               Output: --18 columns--
               Buffers: shared hit=9
               ->  Sort  (cost=15.91..15.91 rows=1 width=1448) (actual time=0.612..0.613 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Output: --18 columns--
                     Sort Key: table1.updated_at DESC
                     Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                     Buffers: shared hit=9
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.table1  (cost=4.32..15.90 rows=1 width=1448) (actual time=0.558..0.558 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Output: --18 columns--
                           Recheck Cond: ((table1.obj_id)::text = 'ID'::text)
                           Filter: ((table1.deleted_at IS NULL) AND (table1.mute_until IS NOT NULL))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 7
                           Heap Blocks: exact=7
                           Buffers: shared hit=9
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table1_obj_id_deleted_at_mute_until_index  (cost=0.00..4.32 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=0.246..0.246 rows=7 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: (((table1.obj_id)::text = 'ID'::text) AND ((table1.deleted_at IS NULL) = true))
                                 Buffers: shared hit=2
         ->  Index Scan using table2_pkey1 on public.table2 b  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=1076) (never executed)
               Output: --47 columns--
               Index Cond: ((b.id)::text = (table1.last_id)::text)
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=18 read=5
 Planning Time: 4.930 ms
 Execution Time: 1.130 ms
(34 rows)
```

Comment: In this case you only have TRUE and FALSE, that's usually not something very useful for an index. An indexscan searching for too many records can make your query slower instead of faster. Could you share the entire query? And a query plan using `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)`, in plain text.

Comment: Absent the query plan asked for by @FrankHeikens, I'm guessing there are more `not null` entries then `null` and the planner calculates it is faster to just sequence scan for the `not null` case. Indexes are not free they require a look up in the index and then a look up in the table, at some point it is faster to skip the index lookup and go directly to the table.

Comment: `Execution Time: 1.130 ms`, well, even if you make a 1000 times faster, you wouldn't notice it. 1ms is usually good enough.

Comment: lol, well, sure... but this is on my dev db that has zero load and about 1/20,000th of the rows. I can't play around with the prod db to test things out.

This same query takes 1,017.504ms on prod. Prod does not yet have my `table1_obj_id_deleted_at_mute_until_index` index, but has a similar index that the planner is using on `obj_id` and `deleted_at`. The plan looks nearly identical, just a different index for `obj_id` and `deleted_at`. Though, it does appear the majority of the "cost" is coming from the inner Sort step.

Comment: Please share the query on the prod environment, not the dev environment that doesn't have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL doesn't reason through the negation operation in this case. To speed up the IS NOT NULL condition, you would need to create the index to match:

```
create index <name> on <table> ((<column> is not null))
```

Or you could make it a partial index:

```
create index <name> on <table> (some_other_colum) where <column> is not null
```

I don't think there is a single btree index you could build to speed up both queries.  But since the IS NULL condition and the IS NOT NULL condition can't both be high selective at the same time, it is likely that an index can only be helpful for one or the other situation anyway.